# Getting undefine result while fetch the data from mongodb from other controller

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and node.js. I am getting issue with fetch mongoDB collection data using node.js.

I have connect the mongodb and try to fetch one collection information from one controller to another controller however I am getting issue like result undefine.

Please see below code which may be help to understand

Userenrollcontroller.js

```
 let response = {};
MongoClient.connect(config.Database.DFARM.connectString, async function (err, client) {
        if (err) {

            let connError = new Error(500, "Error connecting to DFARM database", err);
            // res.status(connError.status).json(connError);
            response.status = false;
            response.message= connError;
            response.secret = '';
         return response;
        console.log("console3", response);
            // return response;
        }
        else {
            response.status = false;
            response.message= 'An identity for the admin23 user "admin" does not exist in the wallet, call the enrollAdmin application before retrying   ' 
            response.secret = '';
            // return response;
            console.log("console", response);
            //   return response;
    client.db(config.Database.DFARM.dbName).collection("User").find(query1).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                    if(err)
                    {

                        console.log('err db',err);
                        response.status = false;
                        response.message= err;
                        response.secret = '';
                        console.log("console7", response);
                        return response;

                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Username DB',docs);//this is result
                        console.log('Username DB',docs[0].secret);
                        secret = docs[0].secret;

                        query1.secret = secret;
                      //   setTimeout(() => console.log(name), 5 * 10)
                        console.log('Role',query1);
                      //   output.docs = docs[0].name;
                      // //  res.json(output);
                      // console.log('Role',output);

                      response.status = true;
                      response.message= 'secret generate';
                      response.secret = secret;
                       return response;
                //       res.json(docs);

                  client.close();// look after sometimes
                    }                  

     })
    }
})
```

Usercontroller.js

```
UserEnrollController = new UserEnrollController();

UserEnrollController.UserEnroll1(VZID).then((result) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("data result", result)
        }, 8000);
```

I am trying to fetch data using .then result however it show undefine. so I put some delay so I can get data however I am still getting result undefine however it should be as "Username DB" data as mention below.

```
username prassemp
Username DB [ { _id: 5d5af662dac4af4733802e44,
    LOGIN_ID: 'prassemp',
    FIRSTNAME: 'prassemp',
    LASTNAME: 'kumar',
    ROLEID: '5',
    PHONE: '5657624345',
    EMAIL: 'prassemp@gmail.com',
    USERNAME: 'prassemp',
    PASSWORD: 'BK@love123',
    REPASSWORD: 'BK@love123',
    otp: true,
    profile: 'true',
    approved: 'true',
    profileimage: true,
    verification: true,
    STATUS: 'ACTIVE',
    END_DATE: '',
    CREATE_DATE: 2019-08-19T19:20:01.000Z,
    CREATE_BY: 'testuser',
    MODIFIED_DATE: 2019-08-25T12:46:33.000Z,
    MODIFIED_BY: 'test user',
    DOB: '',
    ADDRESS_LINE_1: '',
    ADDRESS_LINE_2: '',
    ID_CARD: '',
    LOGIN_ID_UPPER: 'PRASSEMP',
    LAST_LOGGED_IN: '',
    SUPERVISOR: 'Abhi',
    secret: 'PEDqgsOCllDG' } ]
Username DB PEDqgsOCllDG
Role { USERNAME: 'prassemp', secret: 'PEDqgsOCllDG' }
secreat PEDqgsOCllDG
data result undefined // **here getting result as undefine however it should be data as in "Username DB"**
```

Please help I am stuck here for long time and not getting any thing from anywhere which can solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does your FabricClientRegister.UserEnroll(VZID) return a Promise?
If yes,you should check the Promise does resolve a value

Answer (score 0):

It my silly mistake as the function also be into the

> setTimeout(() => {  },timeout);

so result also need to delay for while.

```
 FabricClientRegister.UserEnroll(VZID).then((result) => {
       console.log("data result", result)
        }, 8000);
```

may be it will help new guys like me who will understand about node.js timeout feature

Thanks